# Where is data_directory for homebrew? or for postgresql or how do I solve error, ""global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory"?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, homebrew

I'm having difficulty with postgresql after installing via homebrew. I'm on Mac OS X 10.9.5 (just updated today and did restart).

Note I didn't deliberately change anything from a default postgresql installation via homebrew

PROBLEM

- I can't uninstall postgresql
- I can't log in to view tables / start the "command line" of postgres
- createdb returns an error about pg_filenode.map "no such file or directory"
- initdb returns error wondering where data_directory is (I don't know)

ANY OF THESE WOULD BE SUCCESS

- Log in to psql (so I can create a database or table like I can do in mysql, browse existing tables)
- Uninstall postgres altogether (so I can re-try with postgresql.app)

I've spent almost 10 hours troubleshooting this and come up short.

I've looked at loads of answers already (including SO questions 24132418 and 14510237) though I can't include all links due to not having reputation points yet

Any pointers would be really appreciated!

Below seems lengthy because I have pasted all the logs, please let me know if I have missed some important info though

Thanks, -Mark

DETAILS

I have been working my way through an introduction to Heroku, and they said installing postgresql was a requirment, so I did that using homebrew

```
brew install postgresql
```

I didn't check it, I proceeded building my app, but the next day I run the webapp locally and get error,

```
Request URL:    http://localhost:5000/admin/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory
Exception Location: /Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect, line 164
```

So I want to investigate.
Now I've never used postgresql before, so **I want to "get to the command line" for postgresql**

Please note, I'm a complete newbie and have never used postgresql before.

In mysql I know this would be

```
mysql -u root -p
```

(and then enter password)

I'm unable to do the equivalent in postgresql

```
  moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ postgres
  postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
  You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.
  moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ postgres -V
  postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5
```

The more [detailed heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#set-up-postgres-on-mac) recommend installing postgresql using postgres.app 
I hadn't done this, I used homebrew, so I tried uninstalling postgresql

```
moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ brew uninstall postgres
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1...
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/bin/clusterdb
```

That didn't work, so back to where I was. To figure out what path to specify, I ran

```
brew info postgresql
```

If you scroll down to the bottom of this, you can see it advises me of the path

```
moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ brew info postgres
postgresql: stable 9.3.5 (bottled), devel 9.4beta2
http://www.postgresql.org/
Conflicts with: postgres-xc
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1 (2927 files, 38M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/postgresql.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl ✔, readline ✔
Recommended: ossp-uuid ✔
==> Options
--32-bit
    Build 32-bit only
--enable-dtrace
    Build with DTrace support
--no-perl
    Build without Perl support
--no-tcl
    Build without Tcl support
--with-python
    Build with python support
--without-ossp-uuid
    Build without ossp-uuid support
--devel
    install development version 9.4beta2
==> Caveats
If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x installed,
you may need to remove the previous version first. See:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/issue/2510

To migrate existing data from a previous major version (pre-9.3) of PostgreSQL, see:
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/upgrading.html

When installing the postgres gem, including ARCHFLAGS is recommended:
  ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg

To install gems without sudo, see the Homebrew wiki.

To reload postgresql after an upgrade:
    launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Note: I have ignored the comment at the top:

```
Conflicts with: postgres-xc
    /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1 (2927 files, 38M) *
```

Anyway there we have it, toward the end of that large output it confirms the path for me is /usr/local/var/postgres, so I tried -D

```
moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ postgres -D /usr/local/postgres
postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/usr/local/postgres/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
```

So this time I specified the config file:

```
moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ postgres --config-file=/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf 
postgres does not know where to find the database system data.
This can be specified as "data_directory" in "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf", or by the -D invocation option, or by the PGDATA environment variable.
```

(Out of desperation, I even tried deleting it and going again)

```
                moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
        The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "macuser".
        This user must also own the server process.
The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_GB.UTF-8".
        The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
        The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

        Data page checksums are disabled.

        initdb: directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" exists but is not empty
        If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
        the directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" or run initdb
        with an argument other than "/usr/local/var/postgres".
        moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
        moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
        The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "macuser".
        This user must also own the server process.

        The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_GB.UTF-8".
        The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

        Data page checksums are disabled.

        creating directory /usr/local/var/postgres ... ok
        creating subdirectories ... ok
        selecting default max_connections ... 100
        selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
        creating configuration files ... ok
        creating template1 database in /usr/local/var/postgres/base/1 ... ok
        initializing pg_authid ... ok
        initializing dependencies ... ok
        creating system views ... ok
        loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
        creating collations ... ok
        creating conversions ... ok
        creating dictionaries ... ok
        setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
        creating information schema ... ok
        loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
        vacuuming database template1 ... ok
        copying template1 to template0 ... ok
        copying template1 to postgres ... ok
        syncing data to disk ... ok

        WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
        You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
        --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

        Success. You can now start the database server using:

            postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
        or
            pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile start


    moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ postgres -D /usr/local/postgres
    postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/usr/local/postgres/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
    moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ postgres --config-file=/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf 
    postgres does not know where to find the database system data.
    This can be specified as "data_directory" in "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf", or by the -D invocation option, or by the PGDATA environment variable.
```

So I took a look at that file:

In that in the conf file itself, the data variable is not defined

```
  moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ ls /usr/local/var/postgres/
  PG_VERSION       pg_ident.conf    pg_stat/         pg_xlog/
  base/            pg_multixact/    pg_stat_tmp/     postgresql.conf
  global/          pg_notify/       pg_subtrans/
  pg_clog/         pg_serial/       pg_tblspc/
  pg_hba.conf      pg_snapshots/    pg_twophase/
  moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ vim /usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf
```

shows that the value is commented out (see line 41... almost the whole file is commented out)

```
 35 # FILE LOCATIONS
 36 #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    -
 37 
 38 # The default values of these variables are driven from the -D command-line
 39 # option or PGDATA environment variable, represented here as ConfigDir.
 40 
 41 #data_directory = 'ConfigDir'           # use data in another directory
 42                                         # (change requires restart)
 43 #hba_file = 'ConfigDir/pg_hba.conf'     # host-based authentication file
 44                                         # (change requires restart)
 45 #ident_file = 'ConfigDir/pg_ident.conf' # ident configuration file
 46                                         # (change requires restart)
 47 
 48 # If external_pid_file is not explicitly set, no extra PID file is written.
 49 #external_pid_file = ''                 # write an extra PID file
 50                                         # (change requires restart)
```

HELP: DOES ANYONE KNOW WHAT I SHOULD SPECIFY THAT 'ConfigDir' AS for where data_directory is?

In case helpful
here are contents of the Cellar folder

```
moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/
COPYRIGHT                       homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
HISTORY                         include/
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json            lib/
README                          share/
bin/
```

(I don't understand why I have some postgres files in Cellar and some in usr/local/var)

I tried some other things too:

```
    moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -w start
    sudo: unknown user: postgres
```

That's based on other SO questions

```
    moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ ls -ld /usr/local/var/postgres/
    drwx------  19 macuser  admin   646B 20 Sep 19:46 /usr/local/var/postgres//
    moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ chown -R postgres /usr/local/var/postgres
    chown: postgres: illegal user name
    moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ brew uninstall postgresql
    Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1...
    Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/bin/clusterdb
    moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ brew uninstall postgres
    Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1...
    Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/bin/clusterdb
    moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$
```

As I say, I installed Postgresql only to try out heroku, so here is the error Chrome gives me from the code when I run `foreman start` locally.
(Note "the django app" is just a demo app `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#prepare-the-app`)
It works for `localhost:5000` home, but when I add `/admin` (the page that would interact with a database), I get the following error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/
FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:5000/admin/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Location: /Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect, line 164
Python Executable:  /Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/heroku/awe01/bin/python
```

Full error traceback log here: `http://dpaste.com/3CREGVQ`

Note this answer `https://stackoverflow.com/a/5053003/870121`
recommends createdb not just initdb

And the above error is the same as if I run createdb:

```
moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ createdb /usr/local/var/postgres/
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory
```

Steps advised here
    [Postgres is failing with 'could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map" '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445935/postgres-is-failing-with-could-not-open-relation-mapping-file-global-pg-fileno)
are

```
Remove and re-add the launch agent
Kill the processes for <postgresql version number>
Initialize the db initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
Restart my computer
```

If this is relevant someone please tell me how to "Remove and re-add the launch agent"?
Is is this? (based on the output of the brew info postgresql from earlier)

```
moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ killall postgresql
No matching processes belonging to you were found
moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ killall postgres
No matching processes belonging to you were found
moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

FINALLY
In case it inspires anyone,

```
moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: The /usr/local directory is not writable.
Even if this directory was writable when you installed Homebrew, other
software may change permissions on this directory. Some versions of the
"InstantOn" component of Airfoil are known to do this.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
back to your user account.

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libguide.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libKLF_OGL.dylib

Warning: Some directories in your path end in a slash.
Directories in your path should not end in a slash. This can break other
doctor checks. The following directories should be edited:
    $/Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/aws/ElasticBeanstalkCommandLineTools/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.3/AWSDevTools.sh/macosx/python2.7/    /Users/macuser/Dropbox/code/aws/ElasticBeanstalkCommandLineTools/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.6.3/AWSDevTools/eb/macosx/python2.7/

Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

    git
    git-cvsserver
    git-receive-pack
    git-shell
    git-upload-archive
    git-upload-pack

Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
    echo export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$
```

Earlier today I had this error
    createdb: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
            Is the server running locally and accepting
            connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

as per `http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/tutorial-createdb.html`
but that error seems to have gone away now

Any advice on un or re-installing postgresql, resolving the `unknown user: postgres` error, setting location of `#data_directory = 'ConfigDir'` or any other tips... I would really appreciate it. It's been a full day lost to this now so I would appreciate anything at all.

Comment: Note, when I tried to use the postgres.app installer now it told me "Could not start on Port 5432" and froze during installation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory`

You had a PostgreSQL install, but deleted or moved the data directory while the server was running. Or you installed it on a removable disk that you then removed. Or some application on your system is messing with how other apps change files.

> ```
>   moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ postgres
>   postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
> ```

`postgres` is the server application. The client is `psql`. However, if `global/pg_filenode.map` is missing you're not going to have any more luck with `psql`.

> ```
>   moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ brew uninstall postgres
> ```

`sudo brew uninstall postgres`

> Anyway there we have it, toward the end of that large output it
>   confirms the path for me is `/usr/local/var/postgres`, so I tried `-D`
>
> ```
> moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ postgres -D /usr/local/postgres
> postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/usr/local/postgres/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
> ```

You got the path wrong. Note what "brew info" said:

> ```
>     Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
>     postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
> ```

As for the `postgres` user:

> ```
> moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -w start
> sudo: unknown user: postgres
> ```

I think some Mac OS X installs use `_postgres` or `postgres_`. I don't have a mac, so I can't check. But it doesn't matter in your case anyway, because the datadir is owned by your user, not `postgres`:

> ```
> moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ ls -ld /usr/local/var/postgres/
> drwx------  19 macuser  admin   646B 20 Sep 19:46 /usr/local/var/postgres//
> ```

It looks to me like you or some tool on your system has mangled your PostgreSQL data directory, corrupting it. This shouldn't happen, so I'd be making an effort to find out what removed `pg_filenode.map` and how/when.

If there is no data you care about in the data directory, you should delete it and re-initdb.

I don't have a Mac and I can't see how Homebrew configures your PostgreSQL install's startup, but it sounds like it *probably* runs `postgres` as user `macuser`. In which case, just:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgres -U postgres --auth-local peer --auth-host md5 -E utf-8l
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Finally, re:

> Note, when I tried to use the postgres.app installer now it told me
>   "Could not start on Port 5432" and froze during installation

at a guess, when you tried that you had the `postgres` server from Homebrew already running on 5432, but nonfunctional because of the damaged data directory.

So you really have two things here:

- Re-initdb the datadir to get PostgreSQL working again; and
- Figure out how it got damaged in the first place

Comment: Thanks! I worked through your answer including running `sudo brew uninstall postgres`, which ran

STATUS

 - `/usr/local/Cellar` folder now does NOT contain any `postgresql` folder
 - `postgresql` or `psql` are not recognised commands

WHAT NEXT?

 - Do I need to delete the folder, `/usr/local/var/postgres` which still exists?
 - Should I now run the postgres.app installer? 

I'm reluctant to do either w/o encouragement in case I'm still half way through (un)install

Comment: Here are the contents of existing `/usr/local/var/postgres` folder:
`moriartymacbookair13:~ macuser$ cd /usr/local/var/postgres/`
...
`moriartymacbookair13:postgres macuser$ ls`
...
`PG_VERSION       pg_ident.conf    pg_stat/         pg_xlog/
base/            pg_multixact/    pg_stat_tmp/     postgresql.conf
global/          pg_notify/       pg_subtrans/     postmaster.opts
pg_clog/         pg_serial/       pg_tblspc/       postmaster.pid
pg_hba.conf      pg_snapshots/    pg_twophase/     server.log`

Comment: PS earlier in the day I hadn't missed the "`var`" and the result was the same with the proper path you pointed out
`postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`
As for rest of your answer, I haven't worked through it yet as I need to do un/re-install first. Commands in terminal
`initdb`, `postgresql`, `createdb` return "command not found" for now

Comment: Thanks again @Craig, the sudo brew seems to have been a safe and effective option here, then postgres.app was able to do its thing. Full summary added as separate answer.

Comment: It also solved the problem for those upgrading to Mac OS Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

## SOLUTION to the problem I posted

1. sudo brew uninstall postgresql (literally, sudo solved my problem... I had read that `sudo brew` can be dangerous but it worked well in this case)
2. Restart
3. Tried to run postgres.app  ...got error
4. Restart
5. Fully uninstalled postgres.app (following instructions on site: quit, drag to the Trash, and then "Finder > Empty Trash..." as per `http://postgresapp.com/documentation/install.html`)
6. Restart
7. Delelted data folder as per trouble shooting instructions of postgresapp
   `i.e., the 5 steps here:
   Resetting Postgres.app
   http://postgresapp.com/documentation/troubleshooting.html` (I may have done this earlier, I forget the order of steps 5/7)
8. Restart
9. Re-installed postgresql via postgres.app
10. Added the path to my `/etc/profile` file... adding to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` doesn't work for me for some reason. Here in an

#### Extract from /etc/profile for me

It might be from another file for you, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/why-doesnt-bashrc-run-automatically#comment13715_13019

```
 # 1:
 # For postgresql postgres postgres.app:
 # Otherwise psql isn't a recognised command
 # Based on http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin
 # 2:
 # And this from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH:$PATH"
 # 3:
 # And now this based on error of file not existing
 # from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868730/socket-file-var-pgsql-socket-s-pgsql-5432-missing-in-mountain-lion-os-x-ser -- don't think this made a difference though
export PGHOST=localhost
```

I think this is overkill; the first change is definitely useful as it allows me to go straight to psql just by typing "psql" in terminal (I personally didn't even need `-h localhost`); I'm less sure of the need of the other two additions

That's it.

---

## HOW IT GOT DAMAGED IN THE FIRST PLACE

I haven't figured this out.

---

## OTHER TIPS FOR ANY MAC USER WHO'S USING DJANGO ON HEROKU WITH POSTGRESQL

In case relevant, now that it's working, here are some more steps I've finished to get fully set up and comfortable with postgres and my new heroku app. This has been my first experience with heroku, django and postgresql so I have tried to note all details which struck me!

Note: I had locally finished the tutorial for the "polls" sample app (from `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/`). **My goal was to add this `/polls` app to the "getting started" django sample app** (from `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python`)
(Note: I chose django 1.6 since it seems to be the latest version supported by heroku right now.)

I am running Mac OS X 10.9.5 but some of my comments may be helpful for anyone confused about local/heroku postgres integration

### Create a local postgres db to use with django app

1. Once postgres app is running (launched by double-clicking the program in Applications -> Postgres, then look out for the elephant in the notification bar if you're on a Mac), I can log in to psql. But first straight from the command line, I made a database by command

`createdb cool01db`

Note if you get this, 
   `psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?` or similar error, then you haven't set up the postgres app/server correctly, so don't proceed through my instructions

2. Now I could log in to psql as per instructions on `http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html`
   `psql cool01db`
   Running the psql command `\d` shows me they're nothing in this database yet; tables will be created automatically by django when I do my `syncdb` command
3. Note: Since I had already completed the polls tutorial elsewhere, I had copied the "polls" folder (which contains things like `models.py`) into the folder of my heroku sample app, so "polls" was a folder alongside "gettingstarted" and "hello". Therefore I also added "polls" to the list of "installed apps" in the `gettingstarted/settings.py` as per `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/#activating-models`
4. I edited the gettingstarted/settings.py file as per instructions on the django tutorial
   `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup` and `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASES`
   For me, this looked like:

`DATABASES = {
     'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
         'NAME': 'cool01db',
         'USER': '', 
         'PASSWORD': '',
         'HOST': 'localhost', # '127.0.0.1' probably works also
         'PORT': '5432',
     }
 }`

### To use the newly-created local postgres DB and not the heroku one

5. I commented out this link in `gettingstarted/settings.py`

`#  DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()`

This is as per excellent comment, `http://stackoverflow.com/a/16422414/870121`

6. I navigated into the project folder (which contains the above three folders and files like manage.py) and ran (locally, not on heroku) `python manage.py syncdb`
   Here I was prompted to create a `superuser` with a password

Note, now the tables for the heroku sample app (tables like `hello_greeting`) **and** the django polls app (tables like `polls_choice` and `polls_question`) are all automatically created in the local postgres db, and I can view them if I log in to psql (`psql cool01db` from the terminal) and type `\d` (once you're in)

7. I ran `foreman start` and navigated to `http://localhost:5000/admin/` and entered my superuser username and password I had just created. This successfully logged me in to the /admin site powered by my LOCAL postgres database
8. I saw the admin panel with the opportunity to add a Question as per django tutorial, so I added a question with some answers as per `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial02/#make-the-poll-app-modifiable-in-the-admin`
9. Now I visited `http://localhost:5000/polls` and sure enough it was working
10. If in the terminal I ran `psql cool01db` and then the sql command `\d` I could see the tables, and `select * from question_choice` showed me the updates just made. Very satisfying.

### To use the heroku postgres db in development

11. I uncommented this line in `gettingstarted/settings.py`

`DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()`

12. I ran `heroku config`
    Knew to do this from `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#define-config-vars`
    Output was this:

`(awe01)moriartymacbookair13:getstartapp macuser$ heroku config
=== awe01 Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:                 postgres://aqmorelettersqz:uqry_pnFmorelettersYf@ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dbmorelettersce
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YELLOW_URL: postgres://aqmorelettersqz:uqry_pnFmorelettersYf@ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dbmorelettersce
PAPERTRAIL_API_TOKEN:         kmorelettersx
TIMES:                        2
(awe01)moriartymacbookair13:getstartapp macuser$`

Then **I pasted all of that into the hidden file `.env`** which lies in the same folder as manage.py

Syntax note: this means the file .env looked like this:

`TIMES=2
DATABASE_URL=postgres://aqmorelettersqz:uqry_pnFmorelettersYf@ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dbmorelettersce
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YELLOW_URL=pos....` etc

...i.e., with `=` signs but no spaces around them (and no comments in this file)

Note, this involved deleting the original "DATABASE_URL=" entry from the .env file

As far as I understand, the .env file is what your local machine sees, but the output of "heroku config"  is what the heroku machine sees (corrections welcome), so I wanted them to match.

13. NB: Once Postgres is installed and you can connect, you’ll need to export the DATABASE_URL environment variable for your app to connect to it when running locally.

Run command `export DATABASE_URL=postgres:///$(whoami)`

This tells Postgres to connect locally to the database matching your user account name (which is set up as part of installation).

That's from `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup`

Note (to self): I don't understand what happens here (I can't see a file that's changed as a result of running this, or what exactly happens). But I did a restart of computer and everything still works, I didn't need to run this again.

14. Now on a heroku dyno I ran "syncdb"
    `heroku run python manage.py syncdb`

(You will be prompted to create a superuser only if you haven't already done so)

15. I went to myappname.herokuapp.com/admin and logged in with the superuser account created for heroku postgresql (which I have the same as local for convenience). There I was able to add a question, and this time this question is added to the heroku postgresql db. Visiting myappname.herokuapp.com/polls shows me that question available for votes

I think that's it

Now if I do `foreman start`, what I see at /db or /polls is the same as if I visit my locallhost:5000 or myappname.herokuapp.com, since both are using the heroku postgresdb (I don't even need my postgres server running)

16. To view tables and run commants like `\dt` or `SELECT * FROM...` I can do a command `heroku pg:psql` as per `https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#provision-a-database`

Thanks Craig Ringer for the original answer.